# Split one string into different strings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, split

i have the text in a string as shown below

```
011597464952,01521545545,454545474,454545444|Hello this is were the message is.
```

Basically i would like each of the numbers in different strings to the message eg

```
NSString *Number1 = 011597464952 
NSString *Number2 = 01521545545
etc
etc
NSString *Message = Hello this is were the message is.
```

i would like to have that split out from one string that contains it all

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I would use `-[NSString componentsSeparatedByString]`:

```
NSString *str = @"011597464952,01521545545,454545474,454545444|Hello this is were the message is.";

NSArray *firstSplit = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
NSAssert(firstSplit.count == 2, @"Oops! Parsed string had more than one |, no message or no numbers.");
NSString *msg = [firstSplit lastObject];
NSArray *numbers = [[firstSplit objectAtIndex:0] componentsSepratedByString:@","];

// print out the numbers (as strings)
for(NSString *currentNumberString in numbers) {
  NSLog(@"Number: %@", currentNumberString);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Look at [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) `componentsSeparatedByString` or one of the similar APIs.

If this is a known fixed set of results, you can then take the resulting array and use it something like:

```
NSString *number1 = [array objectAtIndex:0];    
NSString *number2 = [array objectAtIndex:1];
...
```

If it is variable, look at the [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) APIs and the `objectEnumerator` option.

Comment: yeah I found that earlier but how do i put each array into a separate string ?

Comment: Added a little more detail to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *strings = [[@"011597464952,01521545545,454545474,454545444|Hello this is were the message is." componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@",|"]] mutableCopy];

NString *message = [[strings lastObject] copy];
[strings removeLastObject];

// strings now contains just the number strings
// do what you need to do strings and message

....

[strings release];
[message release];
```

Answer (score 0):

does objective-c have `strtok()`?

The strtok function splits a string into substrings based on a set of delimiters.
Each subsequent call gives the next substring.

```
substr = strtok(original, ",|");
while (substr!=NULL)
{
   output[i++]=substr;
   substr=strtok(NULL, ",|")
}
```

Comment: No, but C does, and since Objective-C is a strict superset of C, Objective-C gets it for free.

Comment: You can use `strtok` in Objective-C (it is a superset of C), but `strtok` expects C-style strings. `NSString` is not the same beast at all. It is a unicode string. Although you can get a C-style string (given an encoding), I wouldn't go down this route.

Comment: It would, but you'd have to use C strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a handy function I use:

```
///Return an ARRAY containing the exploded chunk of strings
///@author: khayrattee
///@uri: http://7php.com
+(NSArray*)explodeString:(NSString*)stringToBeExploded WithDelimiter:(NSString*)delimiter
{
    return [stringToBeExploded componentsSeparatedByString: delimiter];
}
```