# Reformat NSString in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I have the following NSString which I then want to split into two:

```
NSString *tmpString = @"Mike <test@gmail.com>";
```

I want to make two strings out of it that would look like this:

```
NSString *tmpString1 = @"Mike";
NSString *tmpString2 = @"test@gmail.com";
```

How can I achieve this in Objective-C? Thanks in advance!

Comment: use the method  `componentsSeparatedByString` of `NSString` or use [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Please look this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470756/split-one-string-into-different-strings

Comment: The real question is whether you want to split on the space or whether you want to parse RFC-822 (or the later version) compliant email addresses.   If the latter, none of the answers below are correct.

Comment: @bbum what's the difference between the RFC-822 and the ordinary email address?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Comment: Whatever you do, I'd suggest a unit test that feeds a massive list of email addresses through your code. This is onetime where scraping your spam box might prove useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how it is done,

```
NSArray *tmpArray = [@"Mike <test@gmail.com>" componentsSeparatedByString:@"<"];
NSString *tmpString1 = [tmpArray objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString *tmpString2 = [tmpArray objectAtIndex: 1];

tmpString2 = [tmpString2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
tmpString1 = [tmpString1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: No need of thanks, even i solved this problem but your answer is better, shorter than me.

Comment: This solution will fail with strings like: `Mike Smith <test@foo.com>` or addresses line `test@foo.com`. Not all email addresses have the display name.

Comment: I invite you to check the new code,

Comment: Won't work with *"much.more unusual"@example.com*, which is a valid (though quite odd) address. Pedantic, yes, but standards exist for a reason.

Comment: I've edited your answer after trying it out in Xcode. Thanks! It worked!

Comment: @ThilinaHewagama: Now your code is just like me :)

Comment: @rmaddy: What about my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do what you want.

You could split the string on whitespace ([`-[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a)), then trim away the extraneous `<` and `>` you don't want with [`-[NSString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet%3a).

You can look for the indexes of the characters `<` and `>` with [`-[NSString rangeOfString:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3a) and copy out the substrings with [`-[NSString substringToIndex:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringToIndex%3a) and [`-[NSString substringWithRange:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringWithRange%3a).

Another method is to use [`NSScanner`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:tmpString];
[scanner scanUpToString:@" <" intoString:&tmpString1];
[scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&tmpString2];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this in one line of code, here's how...

Note: I've used this with great success using exactly the same format you use, using regular expressions.  This, in my opinion, is a little simpler and can be achieved with a single line of code as illustrated in my example.  Should your format ever change, you would only need to make very minor changes to your regular expression:

```
NSArray *nameComponents = [@"Mike <test@gmail.com>" componentsSeparatedByRegex:@"\\s<(.*)>"];
NSLog(@"included in nameComponents array: %@", nameComponents);
```

Output:

> 2013-02-26 11:34:55.238 TestProject[39086:1c403] included in nameComponents array: (
>       Mike,
>       "test@gmail.com"
>   )

The example, of course, assumes you use a strict format of "[name][space]<[email]>".  However, as mentioned, any format changes would be a simple matter of tweaking your regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You need to break the string as:

```
NSString *tmpString = @"Mike <test@gmail.com>";

NSArray *breakIntoStrings=[tmpString componentsSeperatedByString:@"<"];
//[0]=Mike
//[1]=test@gmail.com>

NSString *tmpString1 = breakIntoStrings[0];
NSString *tmpString2 = [breakIntoStrings[1] substringToIndex:[breakIntoStrings[1] length] - 1];

//now tmpString1 contains white space at end. you can trim it by:

tmpString1 = [tmpString1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                              [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 1):

there are different ways to achieve this depending on your requirements, but when you use `componentsSeparatedByString`, it returns an `NSArray` object no `NSString` and you can use that array to get the index strings,

```
NSArray *mainStrArray = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"<"];
```

now your array conatins the values  Mike  at index 0 and test@gmail.com> at index 1

// for getting mike, just remove the white space after it

```
NSString *stringMike=[[mainStrArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                          [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

// iterate again the other part to get the remaining string..

```
NSArray *tmpArray=[[mainStrArray objectAtIndex:1] componentsSepratedByString:@">"];
```

// you wil get the at index 0 test@gmail.com
  //parse again its first part

```
NSString *testStr=[tmpArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

other alternate as I have mentioned in comment earlier was [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html)