# Break NSString into Latitude and Longitude Coordinates and Re-Center MapView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an NSString with the value of:

```
NSString *combined = "10014, 40.734, -74.0053";
```

I would like to break this string where there are commas into three NSStrings that called bZip, bLat, and bLon so that the values would be like below:

```
bZip = 10014 
bLat = 40.734 
bLon = -74.0053
```

I would then like to use the bLat and bLon coordinates to update the center location on a MapView. The MapView pulls data from a JSON feed and plots the markers out, but I need to re-focus the map on the coordinates that were saved in the values for bLat and bLon.

I am assuming that I need to make this change after the line:

```
[self.mapView1 addAnnotations:newAnnotations];
```

Does anyone know how to help me make this happen? Thank you all!

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:0
                                                   error:&error];

CLLocationCoordinate2D location;                        
NSMutableArray *newAnnotations = [NSMutableArray array]; 
MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation;                        

for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array)
{   
    location.latitude = [dictionary[@"placeLatitude"] doubleValue];
    location.longitude = [dictionary[@"placeLongitude"] doubleValue];

    newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:dictionary[@"name"]
                                               andCoordinate:location];

    [newAnnotations addObject:newAnnotation];


}

[self.mapView1 addAnnotations:newAnnotations];
```

Comment: 1. This is not related to Xcode. 2. Have you googled this? There are **tons** of dupes on Stack Overflow and at other places as well. 3. If not, have you at least **tried** to do something yourself? This is **trivial,** I could enumerate 3 or 4 ways to do this off the top of my head.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C Split()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558888/objective-c-split) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259956/nsstring-tokenize-in-objective-c) and [this one too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095349/how-to-split-strings-in-objective-c) and [this question as well.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470756/split-one-string-into-different-strings)

Comment: @H2CO3, thanks for letting me know not ton include Xcode in the tag for iOS development questions. In answer to question 2 - yes, I have googled it. Not quite yet trivial for me, but one day hope to be able to rattle off 3 or 4 ways to do this. Thanks much :)

Comment: @H2CO3, recommend closing this? or should I leave it open for others to learn from. Don't want to clutter SO... thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Since there are already four dupes, I'd recommend that you please delete it. In my opinion, we don't need more of this question. (You'll also get your lost 14 reputation back.)

Comment: It is too late to delete it on your own now, because it has answers.

Comment: will do. thanks much! wow that hurt my points. I'll recover.

Comment: Im closing it now. sorry for the distraction.

Comment: @Brandon No problem, it'll then most likely be community-deleted. If you take a piece of advice, next time it'll be worth using the search feature of Stack Overflow itself too (with some relevant keywords, you are very likely to find an already existing answer to basic questions.)

Comment: thanks @H2CO3. Any idea how to unlock an account. Reputation was destroyed and can't ask questions (wasn't planning to ask another question, but have heard of this happening). Will this unlock itself over time?

Comment: thanks @H2CO3. I'll learn better. Have a good one.

Comment: Thank you all for keeping SO free of poor questions. I apologize mine. In an attempt to make it more appropriate for SO, I have updated my question to target a more problematic issue that I am facing. Please feel free to help me out. If you think this question is more in line with the guidelines of SO, please also feel free to up vote, or un-downvote, this question. Thank you all!

Comment: @Brandon: Don't do that. you'll get more down votes. You should ask different question for different problem. This is not the good way to get up-votes.

Comment: Oh. Ok Vin. Got blasted by this question and lost ability to ask questions. Trying to regain some composure. Thanks for message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sample Code :**

```
NSArray *stringArray = [combined componentsSeparatedByString: @","];

NSString *bZip = [stringArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *bLat = [stringArray objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *bLon = [stringArray objectAtIndex:2];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 NSString *combined = @"10014, 40.734, -74.0053";
 NSArray *array = [combined componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one

```
    NSString *combined = "10014, 40.734, -74.0053";
    NSArray *data = [combined componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];

NSLog(@"bZip = %@",[data objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"bLat = %@",[data objectAtIndex:1]);
NSLog(@"bLon = %@",[data objectAtIndex:2]);
```